# JavaScript Help (Writing/Editing HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## EDIT / UPDATE #2

@Martin This is my current code. The only problems I have now is the position of it, and the displays of it. I currently merged my `latest.js` file (navigation section) to a new `nav.js` file, so that it doesn't interfere with other pages.

```
var menu = document.getElementById("navigation")
var args = ["index", "chat", "games", "gamingreviews", "contact",];

function displayMenu() {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.className = "navlinks";
    args.forEach(function(name, index) {
        var li = document.createElement('li'),
            an = document.createElement('a');
        li.className = "navlinks"
        an.innerHTML = name;
        an.setAttribute('href', "http://www.thehideout.somee.com/" + name + ".html");
        li.appendChild(an);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    menu.appendChild(ul);
}
displayMenu();
```

Comment: What kind of element is `#output2` ?  What is the expected HTML-structure `displayArgs()` shall generate ?

Comment: @Martin Ernst It's for the ID part of the element, e.g. "<div id="output1"> and then that piece of code will target that div element. displayArgs is what was used to generate the sidebar news for each page automatically, which had information not worth inserting into the code, but that's working fine; it's the bottom part of creating a "li" as apart of the navigation menu to have it say "About" for example with the href of the page thehideout.somee.com/(about.html)

Comment: Try to change 4 points: 1) You have included script `latest.js` 2 times in the body. Do it 1 time in the head. 2) You have added a line `li.innerHTML = ''` inside displayMenu. It's overflouos, remove it. 3) You use 2 times the same variable name `out`. Replace every `out` that comes after `displayArgs` with `menu`, even inside displayMenu. 4) There's another "<div>" nested in "#output2". Attach the menu to that div by changing `var out = document.getElementById("output2");` to `var menu = document.getElementById("navigation");`

Comment: I get the same results. It fixed the padding problem, causing the header background and the sidebar to not be separated, but I just need 1 simple fix; to get the JavaScript to include the class inside the div for the links so it appears correctly. Couldn't I do `li.setAttribute("class", "navlinks");`?

Comment: Yeah, inside `displayMenu` you may set attributes or classnames for `ul, li,` and `an` as you need to make yor css matching. The names I gave are only examples.

Comment: @Martin Ernst I got it, but it's not COMPLETELY correct. It's off centered, going to the bottom left, and its also still showing the page name, which I need a way to get it to be another javascript line element to make it turn into something different; making "index" turn into "About" and "gamingreviews" turn into "The Hideout" and so fourth.

Comment: 1) You **should'nt** give `ul` **and** `li` same class, only `ul`. 2) Position and display is part of the right css. If there are problems you should post a new question. **We should not misuse stackoverflow as an development-playground!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a menu as an unordered list appended to #output2.

```
var out = document.getElementById("output2");
var args = ["About", "Chat", "Games", "Gaming Reviews", "Contact",];

function displayMenu() {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.className = "mainMenu";
    args.forEach(function(name, index) {
        var li = document.createElement('li'),
            an = document.createElement('a');
        li.className = "mmenu-item-" + index;
        an.innerHTML = name;
        an.setAttribute('href', "http://www.thehideout.somee.com/" + name + ".html");
        li.appendChild(an);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    out.appendChild(ul);
}
displayMenu();
```

I have given classNames to elements for easy styling, change them to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, it kind of works; please check updated question.

Comment: @ The Gaming Hideout . Your css can't match the menu, because there is no `.navlinks` inside `#navigation`. Two ways out: Write in your css always `#navigation.navlinks` without space **or**  make change inside displayMenu `ul.className = "navlinks";`.

Comment: I did do the navlinks just now, and like I said before, it is now off centered bottom left, but similar to what I had before. Plus, it is showing the page name which it needs to be set that for the html element to work; is there a `code` such as `innerHTML` that can fix that? I'm currently merging my second half of the JS (the navigation) to a new file, so you know.

Comment: **OP has edited his question completely. It is no longer possible to see for what question this answer is given!**